# Can Redgate's Flyway migration tool migrate data and schemas between 2 different databases?

Tags: database, migration, flyway

Flyway can do database versioning and migration for 1 Database but I do not see a way to perform an update between 2 different databases such as MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks,

Comment: Seems this is a question for Redgate customer support. Maybe try their user groups.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the SQL is generic enough that it can run on both SQL Server and PostgreSQL. Then, yeah, you can easily do that. You can either set up two config files, one for each different database, then deploy telling flyway through the command line which config file to use. Alternatively, you can specify a different connection string for each deployment to a different database.

That does require two calls to the command line, but that's no different than deploying to two different environments, or to two of the same type of databases, but on different servers.

BUT...

That does assume that the SQL is generic enough. For most people, in most circumstances, they're taking advantage of functionality within  that is superior to . Which means that the SQL will not be generic.